# Does ResultSet object does not have any data once when it has been added to Map object?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a method which processes the data retrieved from a table by adding to Map object (i.e HashMap). But after it has been added to Map object when I am trying to reprint the ResultSet object(dbResultset) data no data is printed. So my doubt is does my code has something worng (or) the there would not be any data in ResultSet object when once it has been added to Map object? Can't I reuse the ResultSet object in any other method?

```
public class DBConnection {
    Map<String, String> authentication=new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Map<String,String> processResultset() {

        try {
            // Retrieving the types and properties of columns from ResultSet   object
            ResultSetMetaData dbMetadata = dbResultset.getMetaData();
            int columnCount=dbMetadata.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println("col count:"+columnCount);
            if(!dbResultset.isBeforeFirst()){
                System.out.println("No Records Found");
            }
            else{
                while(dbResultset.next()){
                    authentication.put(dbResultset.getString(1), dbResultset.getString(2));
                }
                System.out.println(authentication);
                if(dbResultset.isAfterLast()) 
                    System.out.println(" no data exists");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally{
            return authentication;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
col count:2
hi{203=UK, 204=Netherlands, 200=Germany, 201=Romania, 104=Japan, 103=USA, 101=Russia, 100=India}
no data exists
```

Comment: what is your problem? After you added all contents of result set into `authentication` map, result set itself is consumed. It's like an iterator, and cannot be reused after been fully consumed.

Comment: Where is `dbResultset` declared and initialized? JDBC objects (statement, result set) should have a minimal scope so that you don't leak resources. Re-using a `ResultSet` is therefore a bad idea.

Comment: Your cursor is after your last entry. What's the problem. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened is you moved the cursor till the last row by using [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) so when you used [isAfterLast()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isAfterLast()) there were no data to get because you already used [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) and moved the cursor till the last available data and there are no data to get

Comment: Hi Karim, Thanks for the answer and i am using beforeFirst() method to move the cursor to before the first record and the ResultSet object can be reused now.